# Read binary data from pipe in perl

Tags: perl, pipe

I want to write a Perl script which captures binary data from a pipe and read the binary data inside Perl and process the received binary content as file handler.

I am able to receive the binary content from pipe and the problem is here that the binary format is not preserved correctly while reading the data from Perl . The NUL character are not preserved and converted this character as newline in Perl environment. Following is the command line arguments and sample

```
>more D:\Sample_binary.zip| perl readpipe.pl D:\sample_output.txt
```

**readpipe.pl**

```
local $/;   
my $lines = <STDIN>; # Read the binary data from pipe
open my $IN, "+<", \$lines; # Load the content as file handler
$zip = Archive::Zip->new;
$zip->readFromFileHandle ($IN); # Read ZIP file from the received binary data
```

Comment: That's a [useless use of `more`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) (where `more` is even more useless than `cat` because it is useful only for interactive use).  Perl cam read standard input just fine without using an external program.

Comment: But reading the archive from within Perl is probably going to be a lot simpler.  Just pass in an input file name argument to the Perl script.

Comment: Yes. when we use `cat`command, able to read the binary content. I am currently checking this in WINDOWS platform. So i tried with `type` command and getting the raw binary data. Thanks!!

Comment: `>type D:\Sample_binary.zip| perl readpipe.pl D:\sample_output.txt`. Now I am able to load the zip file from pipe.

Comment: @tripleee, My aim is to pass the binary data from pipeline and not passing filename as argument. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: So what's wrong with the NUL-character? What makes you think that Perl converts the `0x00` byte (`\0`) to e.g. `0x0A` (`\n`)?

Comment: @red0ct As per the previous comment, apparently `more` does that? So the workaround is to not use `more`.  Voting to close as trivial.

Comment: A pipe is just a way to pass in data via STDIN.  You can do that like this too: `perl readpipe.pl D:\sample_output.txt < D:\Sample_binary.zip`

Answer (score 4):

When dealing with binary data, use `binmode(STDIN);`. It will prevent CRLF⇔LF conversions, and will disable any encoding layer (added by `use open` or whatever).

> *The NUL character are not preserved and converted this character as newline in Perl environment.*

No, Perl is not doing that. Perhaps `more` is? Use

```
perl readpipe.pl <D:\Sample_binary.zip
```

Comment: Yes. you are correct. Perl allows to read bin mode but more is not allowing NUL character.

Comment: I said that `more` utility is not allowing NULL character in WINDOWS. Your answer gives some idea to resolve another issue. Thanks so much.